# C++ - Creating an integer of bits and nibbles

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

*For a full background (you don't really need to understand this to understand the problem but it may help) I am writing a CLI program that sends data over Ethernet and I wish to add VLAN tags and priority tags to the Ethernet headers.*

The problem I am facing is that I have a single 16 bit integer value that is built from three smaller values: `PCP` is 3 bits long (so 0 to 7), `DEI` is 1 bit, then `VLANID` is 12 bits long (0-4095). `PCP` and `DEI` together form the first 4 bit nibble, 4 bits from `VLANID` add on to complete the first byte, the remaining 8 bits from `VLANID` form the second byte of the integer.

`11123333 33333333`

1 == `PCP` bits, 2 == `DEI` bit, 3 == `VLANID` bits

Lets pretend `PCP` == 5, which in binary is 101, `DEI` == 0, and `VLANID` == 164 which in binary is 0000 10100011. Firstly I need to compile these values together like to form the following:

`10100000 10100101`

The problem I face is then when I copy this integer into a buffer to be encoded onto the wire (Ethernet medium) the bit ordering changes as follows (*I am printing out my integer in binary before it gets copied to the wire and using wireshark to capture it on the wire to compare*):

Bit order in memory: `abcdefgh 87654321`

Bit order on the wire: `8765321 abcdefgh`

I have two problems here really:

- The first is creating the 2 byte integer by "sticking" the three smaller ones together
- The second is ensuring the order of bits is that which will be encoded correctly onto the wire (so the bytes aren't in the reverse order)

Obviously I have made an attempt at this code to get this far but I'm really out of my depth and would like to see someone’s suggestion from scratch, rather than posting what I have done so far and someone suggestion how to change that it to perform the required functionality in a possibly hard to read and long winded fashion.

Comment: look at ntoh and hton (net to host and host to net). The issue is big/little endian.

Comment: Use the `hton` family of functions to deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is byte ordering, rather than bit ordering. Bits in memory don't really have an order because they are not individually addressable, and the transmission medium is responsible for ensuring that the discrete entities transmitted, octets in this case, arrive in the same shape they were sent in.

Bytes, on the other hand, are addressable and the transmission medium has no idea whether you're sending a byte string which requires that no reordering be done, or a four byte integer, which may require one byte ordering on the receiver's end and another on the sender's.

For this reason, network protocols have a declared 'byte ordering' to and from which all sender's and receivers should convert their data. This way data can be sent and retrieved transparently by network hosts of different native byte orderings.

POSIX defines some functions for doing the required conversions:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);
uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);
uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong);
uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort);
```

'n' and 'h' stand for 'network' and 'host'. So htonl converts a 32-bit quantity from the host's in-memory byte ordering to the network interface's byte ordering.

Whenever you're preparing a buffer to be sent across the network you should convert each value in it from the host's byte ordering to the network's byte ordering, and any time you're processing a buffer of received data you should convert the data in it from the network's ordering to the host's.

```
struct { uint32_t i; int8_t a, b; uint16_t s; } sent_data = {100000, 'a', 'b', 500};

sent_data.i = htonl(sent_data.i);
sent_data.s = htons(sent_data.s);

write(fd, &sent_data, sizeof sent_data);

// ---

struct { uint32_t i; int8_t a, b; uint16_t s; } received_data;

read(fd, &received_data, sizeof received_data);

received_data.i = ntohl(received_data.i);
received_data.s = ntohs(received_data.s);

assert(100000 == received_data.i && 'a' == received_data.a &&
       'a' == received_data.b && 500 == received_data);
```

Although the above code still makes some assumptions, such as that both the sender and receiver use compatible char encodings (e.g., that they both use ASCII), that they both use 8-bit bytes, that they have compatible number representations after accounting for byte ordering, etc.

---

Programs that do not care about portability and inter-operate only with themselves on remote hosts may skip byte ordering in order to avoid the performance cost. Since all hosts will share the same byte ordering they don't need to convert at all. Of course if a program does this and then later needs to be ported to a platform with a different byte ordering then either the network protocol has to change or the program will have to handle a byte ordering that is neither the network ordering nor the host's ordering.

---

Today the only common byte orderings are simply reversals of each other, meaning that hton and ntoh both do the same thing and one could just as well use hton both for sending and receiving. However one should still use the proper conversion simply to communicate the intent of the code. And, who knows, maybe someday your code will run on a PDP-11 where hton and ntoh are not interchangeable.